# gradient descent with momemtum formula

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Following is from deep learning course from Andrew Ng

SGD with momemtum. In implementation details professor mentioned as below

```
v(dw) = beta * v(dw) + (1-beta)dw
v(db) = beta * v(db) + (1-beta)db

W = W - alpha * v(dw)
b = b - alpha * v(db)
```

another formula

```
v(dw) = beta * v(dw) +  dw
v(db) = beta * v(db) +  db

W = W - alpha * v(dw)
b = b - alpha * v(db)
```

And the net effect of using this version of second is that vdW ends up 
being scaled by a factor of 1 minus Beta, or really 1 over 1 minus Beta. 
And so when you're performing these gradient descent updates, alpha just needs 
to change by a corresponding value of 1 over 1 minus Beta.

In practice, both of these will work just fine, it just affects what's the best value of the learning
rate alpha. But I find that this particular formulation is a little less intuitive.
Because one impact of this is that if you end up tuning the hyperparameter Beta,
 then this affects the scaling of vdW and vdb as well. And so you end up needing to retune
the learning rate, alpha, as well, maybe.

Question: What does professor mean by if we tune hyper parameter beta which will effect dw and db. My understanding is that in earlier version too beta parameter effects dw and db? Kindly elaborate.

Another question what does professor mean that you need to return to turning learning rate alpha as well?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha and beta are both hyper parameters and can be adjusted to make SGD more effective. The stochastic bit in SGD means that the data is noisy and scattered around the average value. Beta essentially determines the number of data points which averaged over which is given by b/(1-b). So beta is tuned, that is adjusted, so that the data fit is smoother but not over fitted.

Alpha is the step size in gradient descent, it is tuned so that the cost function decreases on each iteration and the minimum is found. If alpha is too big the algorithm can fail and the minimum won’t be found. Conversely if alpha is too small the algorithm will be very slow. For more details see [SGD](https://towardsdatascience.com/stochastic-gradient-descent-with-momentum-a84097641a5d)

References: